# why does this background image work in Chrome and FF but not IE 8?

Tags: css

CSS

```
.arrow {
background:url(images/arrow.png) center left no-repeat;
padding-left:23px;
padding-right:10px;
border-right:0px solid #e6e6e6;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="arrow"><h3>Technical Documentation</h3></div>
```

It works just fine in FF and Chrome. The style is being applied in IE, I know because I see the padding, however, the image does not appear.

Comment: What version of IE?  Could be it doesn't support png?  Post it on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect syntax, please try:

```
background: #000 url(images/arrow.png) center left no-repeat;
```

Comment: That solved it. So, IE needs a background color defined first? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you use shortcut syntax, yes.